# Remember list item states while navigating in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

If we create state for a list item like val `state = remember(it) { mutableStateOf(ItemState()) }` then we lose expanded state while scrolling.

If we move state generation up higher before `LazyColumn` then expand state saves properly

```
 val states = items.map { remember(it) { mutableStateOf(ItemState()) } }
 LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {....
```

But when we expand an item, click the button, go to the details screen and then go back to items we lose expanded state.
What is the best way to save items' state?

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            RememberStateTheme {
                val navController = rememberNavController()

                NavHost(navController, startDestination = "items") {
                    composable("items") {
                        Greeting(
                            onItemClick = { navController.navigate("details/$it") }
                        )
                    }
                    composable(
                        "details/{index}",
                        arguments = listOf(navArgument("index") { type = NavType.IntType })
                    ) { backStackEntry ->
                        DetailsScreen(backStackEntry.arguments?.getInt("index") ?: -1)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(
    onItemClick: (Int) -> Unit
) {
    val items = remember { (0..100).toList() }

    Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
        val states = items.map { remember(it) { mutableStateOf(ItemState()) } }

        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            items(items) { item ->
                // If we create state here like val state = remember(it) { mutableStateOf(ItemState()) }
                // then we loose expanded state while scrolling
                // If we lift up states generating higher before LazyColumn then expand state
                // is saving properly
                //
                // But when we expand an item, click the button and then go back to items we loose
                // expanded state
                val state = states[item]

                key(item) {
                    Item(index = item,
                        state = state.value,
                        onClick = { onItemClick(item) },
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .clickable {
                                state.value.changeState()
                            }
                    )
                }
                Divider()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Item(
    index: Int,
    state: ItemState,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Box(modifier = modifier) {
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = index.toString(),
                modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)

            )

            if (state.expanded) {
                Button(
                    onClick = onClick,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Click me")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class ItemState {

    val expanded: Boolean
        get() = _expanded.value

    private val _expanded = mutableStateOf(false)

    fun changeState() {
        _expanded.value = !_expanded.value
    }
}

@Composable
fun DetailsScreen(
    index: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Gray.copy(alpha = 0.3f))
    ) {
        Text(
            text = index.toString(),
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using `rememberSaveable` solves the problem.

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1424349/leland-richardson

```kotlin
    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        items(items) { item ->
            val state = rememberSaveable(item) { mutableStateOf(ItemState()) }
    
            key(item) {
                Item(index = item,
                    state = state.value,
                    onClick = { onItemClick(item) },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .clickable {
                            state.value.changeState()
                        }
                )
            }
            Divider()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you by any chance have resources on how this is fully implemented?

Answer (score 6):

> But when we expand an item, click the button, go to details screen and then go back to items we loose expanded state.

Correct. `remember()` remembers for **the scope of a specific composition**. This means it remembers across recompositions, but not when the composition is replaced by a separate composition. In your case, navigation replaces your `Greeting()` composition with a `DetailsScreen()` composition.

> What is the best way to save items state?

Hoist the state further, to a composition that does not get replaced by navigation. In this case, that would be your root composition, where you have your `rememberNavController()` call.

Or, have the state be stored in a viewmodel that is scoped to your activity, or at least to that root composition.

If you want to have this state persist beyond the life of your process, I think that the vision is that we should use effects to save the state via a repository to some persistent store (e.g., JSON file) and restore the state from that store. However, I have not experimented with this approach yet.

Comment: @АлексейГвоздицкий: Then use the viewmodel approach. Also, you could look into using custom ambients, but Googlers generally try to steer developers away from this. You could also say that your composable functions are not top-level functions, but instead are functions on `MainActivity`, and you can store state in activity properties. This too is something Googlers do not recommend, as they prefer that composables be as close to pure functions as possible (i.e., all inputs are via parameters).

Comment: Looks legit. But I have some doubts. 1. Hoist state further to the composition that doesn't have a clue about entities of my "Greeting" screen looks strange.  2. Store view states like expanded or collapsed in viewmodels also is not a good architecture decision

Comment: @АлексейГвоздицкий: "Store view states like expanded or collapsed in viewmodels also is not a good architecture decision" -- I disagree. After all, even in the classic `View` system, you need that state to survive a configuration change, and that is what a viewmodel is for.

Comment: Maybe you are right. But mixing view state storing in views and viewmodels is confusing me a little bit. Viewmodel is good for storing data states and compose state system for local view states. Thank you for your answers!